# UICollectionView inside UITableViewCell scroll behaviour

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to implement something similar to iTunes Store UI.

[image]

As you can see from the picture, there are two directions of scrolling possible. But I would like to prioritise scrolling of UICollectionView which is to the left or right because currently scroll down and scroll left/right are conflicting and causing weird behaviour.

Way to duplicate:
Scroll Down UITableView and then quickly try to swipe right or left on UICollectionView. UITableView will continue to scroll.

How can I do so? Do I need to use GestureRecognizer?

Comment: Why not just use a collection view for the entire display?

Comment: Did you tried using `UIContainerView`

Comment: @jithin how would that help me?

Comment: Am not Sure please check this links ,http://www.appcoda.com/uiscrollview-introduction/ it may helps you

Answer (score -1):

I always avoid collection view as it provides less flexibility to work with auto layout compared to a table view, however not against collection view every time. You should try the adding collection view inside a table view

There is a number of tutorials available for the same. eg ([ios 8 Swift - TableView with embedded CollectionView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31582378/ios-8-swift-tableview-with-embedded-collectionview))