# Can UITableView scroll with UICollectionView inside it?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have the structures below...

[image]

I wrap two of collection views into tableview

One is in tableview header(Collection1), another is in tableview 1st row(Collection2).

All the functions are good (Both collection view).

just...

When I scroll up in Collection2, Collection1 will Not scroll up together, because I'm only scrolling the collectionViews not the tableview.

It only scroll together when I scroll in Collection1.

Is it possible to make the header view scroll with user just like app store's index carousel header?

Or I just went to the wrong place, I should use other ways to approach.

Comment: Do you want collectionView2 to scroll vertically ?. If not disable that, then scroll vertical is only for tableView

Comment: "Can UITableView scroll with UICollectionView inside it?" Yes, of course. What's the reason of letting the first collection view to be in a header instead of a cell? are you aiming to let it be sticky (doesn't move when scrolling the table view)?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31582378/ios-8-swift-tableview-with-embedded-collectionview https://github.com/ashfurrow/Collection-View-in-a-Table-View-Cell

Comment: Give Height constant > 0 to collectionview inside the tableview cell, now when you set data to collection view (after reload) set height constant same as content size.height fo collection view

Answer (score 13):

## Solution

- When you keep CollectionView1 as a TableViewHeader, CollectionView1 will always on the top of TableView after it reaches top. If you want Collection1 and Collection2 scroll up together, you need to keep CollectionView1 in a cell, not a header.
- Make sure CollectionView2 content height smaller or equal to TableViewCell's height. As I checked on App Store, they always make SubCollectionView content height equal to TableViewCell's height (If they use TableView).

## Result

[image]

For more detail, you can take a look at my sample project

https://github.com/trungducc/stackoverflow/tree/app-store-header

Comment: his problem that `UICollectionView`, which located inside `UITableViewCell`, has `vertical` scrolling, so obviously it will not work. Because while he is scrolling `UICollectionView` - `UITableView` will not be scrolled

Comment: **Make sure CollectionView2 content height smaller or equal to TableViewCell's height.** Did I forget to give a solution for it? @TarasChernyshenko

Answer (score 4):

### Problem

1) Your tableview cell **Collectionview**  (let's say collection2) , Collection 2 is scrollable. So when you scroll up tableview won't scroll up

### Solution

1) Just simple and working solution would be **height constant**  , You have to give height constant to the **collection2** with **>=** relationship and **0** Constant value and **750** priority !!

Now the question is how to use this

You need to take `IBOutlet` of Height constant to your custom tableview cell and need to manage the collectionview height from there.

Here is example

```
class FooTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {


    static let singleCellHeight = 88;

    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var descriptionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var iconsCollectionView: IconsCollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var const_Height_CollectionView: NSLayoutConstraint!

    var delegateCollection : TableViewDelegate?

var bars:[Bar] = [] {
        didSet {
            self.iconsCollectionView.reloadData()
            iconsCollectionView.setNeedsLayout()
            self.layoutIfNeeded()

            let items:CGFloat = CGFloat(bars.count + 1)
            let value = (items / 3.0).rounded(.awayFromZero)

            const_Height_CollectionView.constant =  CGFloat((iconsCollectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout).itemSize.height * value)

            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        iconsCollectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        iconsCollectionView.initFlowLayout(superviewWidth: self.frame.width)
        iconsCollectionView.setNeedsLayout()
        iconsCollectionView.dataSource = self
        iconsCollectionView.delegate = self
        const_Height_CollectionView.constant =  iconsCollectionView.contentSize.height
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.setNeedsLayout()
    }
}
```

You can check my answer [Making UITableView with embedded UICollectionView using UITableViewAutomaticDimension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48093595/making-uitableview-with-embedded-uicollectionview-using-uitableviewautomaticdime/48208648#48208648) Very similar and 100% working

Another solution You can also take `UICollectionView` with sections which contain another horizontal collectionview , with this solution you don't need to manage contentsize for every cell

Hope it is helpful