# Can I set different layout for different section in UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I know:

> UICollectionView must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter.

But sometimes we need more than one kind of layout in a collectionView.

**For example:the first section is normal vertical layout but the second section is waterfall layout.**

So I wonder if there any way to achive it.

I would appreciate it if anyone could give me a useful info.

Comment: You should take a look at this sample https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36620969/can-uitableview-scroll-with-uicollectionview-inside-it/50458809#50458809