# tvOS: Unable to scroll through UICollectionView items when it is implemented like this: UICollectionView inside UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, tvos

I have implemented this:
[image]
By following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=17D02pD1weU).
**Here's the problem:**

- **I am unable to scroll through the collection items.**

I think this has something to do with the fact that the project I followed is for iOS and my project is for tvOS.
I've found a somewhat similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36620969/can-uitableview-scroll-with-uicollectionview-inside-it). An answer linked to this GitHub [Repo](https://github.com/trungducc/stackoverflow/tree/app-store-header) whose implementation doesn't seem that different from mine.

Here's the relevant code:

> ViewController.swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell =
            tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? TableViewCell
            else {
                fatalError("Unable to create explore table view cell")}
        return cell
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 140
    }
}
```

> tableViewCell.swift

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }

}

extension TableViewCell:  UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 50
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionViewCell", for: indexPath)
        return cell
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        // For some reason he chose the measures of collectionViewCell and substracted 2
        return CGSize(width: 139, height: 64)
    }
    
    // Highlight the current cell
    // This doesn't work
       func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didUpdateFocusIn context: UICollectionViewFocusUpdateContext, with coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
           if let pindex  = context.previouslyFocusedIndexPath, let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: pindex) {
               cell.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 0.0
               cell.contentView.layer.shadowRadius = 0.0
               cell.contentView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.0
           }
    
           if let index  = context.nextFocusedIndexPath, let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: index) {
               cell.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 8.0
               cell.contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor
               cell.contentView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor
               cell.contentView.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0
               cell.contentView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.9
               cell.contentView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
               collectionView.scrollToItem(at: index, at: [.centeredHorizontally, .centeredVertically], animated: true)
           }
       }
}
```

In a separate project, I have implemented a collectionView independently. I.e: It was not embedded inside of a tableView. And it **works just fine**.

I copied the code from that project that highlights the selected cell and added it to the `tableViewCell.swift` but it had no impact at all.

**So my question is:**

- **Why am I unable to select a cell and/or scroll through the
  collectionView?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://notes.devlabs.bg/creating-a-catalogue-style-tableview-with-tvos-part-1-3-1f42f68cfcb5):

> By denying the focus of the table cell, the Focus engine will
> automatically find the next focusable view on the screen. And in your
> case, that is the collection view’s cell.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canFocusRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
      return false
    }
```

Comment: Hey this really worked. I was breaking my head about this from a long time. Thanks. Could you tell me how you found this solution?

Comment: By doing this, the rows won't get highlighted. What is work around for that? When i scroll different sections of tableview i want it to be highlighted as well.

Comment: I posted the link to the answer. I'm not sure you can BOTH highlight the tableViewCell and keep this behaviour though. They're mutually exclusive.

Comment: @AG_HIHI Thanks for updating your answer after your work done. You saved the time. I was stuck too.

Comment: Glad I helped :D