# Crashes UITableView with UICollectionViews inside on iOS 9 while scrolling using SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios9

Crashes, UITableView with UICollectionViews inside on iOS 9, but works on ios10 while scrolling (scrollToRow) with SWIFT.

In the console, but not sure this is a only reason:

```
*** -[UICollectionView retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7fa8fb085e00
```

I use auto-resizing cells for both of them.

In cellForRowAt of table view I do this:

```
                cell?.collectionView.tag = indexPath.row
                cell?.collectionView.delegate = self
                cell?.collectionView.dataSource = self
                cell?.selectionStyle = .none
                cell?.collectionView.reloadData()
                collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
```

How to properly deal with a such issue?

Comment: I can't figure out when a message could be sending to the deallocated collectionView. The bug is reproduced with some periodization.

Comment: It is difficult to understand the problem of your example. Need more code. Try this sample: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31582378/ios-8-swift-tableview-with-embedded-collectionview/42628971#42628971

Comment: I've tried to move cell?.collectionView.reloadData() to UITableView, willDisplay cell: ,but it didn't help. BTW, I have 3 different types of cells with collections, maybe it influences somehow?

Comment: I suppose it is all about some conflicts when I use 2 different kinds of table cells with collections. Because when I use only one kind it works without crashes.

Comment: when I moved all that code from cellForRowAt to cellWillDisplay, it almost fixed the bug, but anyway it crashes sometimes..

Comment: Can you create full sample for me? I will fix it

Comment: Vasily, I don't know how to do that, the project is too huge and the server side API and so on.. so it is so difficult to make sample project which will simulate real behavior... :(