# Collectionview in tableivew cell. this is bug of reuse

Tags: ios, swift

collectionview in tableviewcell. when tableview reuse cell. collectionview in tableivewcell keep position. this is bug? and how to separate for it. example : cell 1 and cell 10 is collectionview(horizontal). when i scroll cell 1, cell 10 also scroll same postion. please help me.

Answer (score 4):

Create a `Dictionary` to remember the offset for each cell like:

```
var contentOffset: [Int: CGFloat] = [:]
```

When table view cell is being removed from screen store the offset of your collection view like

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let cell = cell as? YouTableViewCell else {
        return
    }

    contentOffset[indexPath.row] = cell.collectionView.contentOffset.x
}
```

Now when cell is about to display restore the content offset like:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let cell = cell as? YouTableViewCell else {
        return
    }

    cell.collectionView.contentOffset.x = contentOffset[indexPath.row] ?? 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not a bug, when table cell being reused, it also reuse the content which is the collection view which is scrolled. Keep Googling and check out the links:

[ios 8 Swift - TableView with embedded CollectionView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31582378/ios-8-swift-tableview-with-embedded-collectionview?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

https://medium.com/@gargankit476/multiple-collection-view-in-uitableview-ced7909a5af3