# How to populate different array values in collection view inside of UITableview using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, uicollectionview

I am created UICollectionView inside of UITableView ,populating array values in UItableview is working perfect, when trying to populate a array values into collectionView getting same values in collectionView of all the rows of tableView, I want  to populate a zeroth index array in collectionview of zeroth row UItableview and so on
below I tried a sample,

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource{


        let array = ["product 1","product 2","product 3","product4"]
        let array1 = ["product id 1","product id 2","product id 3","product id 4"]
        let array2 = [["product id 1","product id 2"],["product id 3","product id 4"],["product id 5","product id 6"],["product id 7","product id 8","product id 9","product id 10","product id 11"]] as [NSArray]


     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return array.count
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell : TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cells") as! TableViewCell
            cell.tableviewlabel1.text = array[indexPath.row]
             cell.tableviewlabel2.text = array1[indexPath.row]
            return cell
        }
     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return array2.count
        }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            let cell : CollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collection", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell


            let rowValue : NSArray = array2[indexPath.row]
            for i in 0..<rowValue.count {
            cell.collectionviewlabel1.text = rowValue[i] as? String
            }
            return cell

        }
```

For example ,I want a zeroth index of array2 values in collectionview of zeroth row of tableview, and first index values in collectionview of first row of tableview and so on.

Comment: Is your collection view is inside tableviewcell?

Comment: Your collection view data source methods should be in your cell class, not in your view controller.

Comment: yeah, I implemented my collectionview inside of uitableviewcell

Comment: then follow the @Paulw11 comment it must be inside in your tableview cell

Comment: Yes, but your cell class must implement `UICollectionViewDataSource`, not your view controller

Comment: yeah, thank you..can u suggest some sample for this @ Paulw11 and V_rohit

Comment: Preferred below link :-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31582378/ios-8-swift-tableview-with-embedded-collectionview or https://medium.com/@aestusLabs/adding-a-uicollectionviews-to-a-custom-uitableviewcell-xib-tutorial-swift-4-xcode-9-2-1ec9ce4095d3

Comment: @KavithaMadhu please note that [I rejected your suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21145653) because you should "_Use '#selector' instead of explicitly constructing a 'Selector'_". (this is an Xcode warning)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First your `array2` has to be like this :

```
let array2 = [["product id 1","product id 2"],["product id 3","product id 4"],["product id 5","product id 6"],["product id 7","product id 8","product id 9","product id 10","product id 11"]]
```

Don't use `NSArray` in Swift. you can write it as [String], [[String]].

Your `ViewController` will have only `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDatasource` methods:

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return array.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell : TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cells") as! TableViewCell
        cell.tableviewlabel1.text = array[indexPath.row]
        cell.tableviewlabel2.text = array1[indexPath.row]

        cell.arrayForCollectionView = array2
        return cell
    }
}
```

Then in your `TableViewCell`:

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var arrayForCollectionView : [[String]]! {
        didSet {
            self.collectionView.reloadData
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

}

extension TableViewCell : UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if (arrayForCollectionView != nil) {
            return arrayForCollectionView.count
        }
        return 0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell : CollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collection", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell


        let rowValue = arrayForCollectionView[indexPath.row]
        for i in 0..<rowValue.count {
            cell.collectionviewlabel1.text = rowValue[i] as? String
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

Let me know if you are getting any issue.

Comment: getting Cannot subscript a value of type '[[String]]!'  error. in  let rowValue : NSArray = arrayForCollectionView[indexPath.row]

Comment: Sorry forgot to remove `NSArray`.

Comment: Hello Amit, I didn't get what I asked ...In my collection view getting product id 2,product id 4,product id 6,product id 11 and all the rows of uitableview

Comment: Thanks Amit ..I just edited in this line "cell.arrayForCollectionView = array2" as " "cell.arrayForCollectionView = array2[indexpath.row]" ..its working perfect ,thanks for ur contribution

Answer (score 1):

**Giving an example for that:**

first tableView is inside ViewController

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController {

//MARK:- IBOUTELTS
//MARK:-
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

//MARK:- VARIABLES
//MARK:-

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


}


}

extension YourViewConroller: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {


}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


}

}
```

And Your CollectionView is inside TableViewCell

```
 extension YourTableViewCell: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {



}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

}


}
```

And make different class for TableView and CollectionView:

```
 class YourTableViewCell: UITableViewCell { // tableview cell

}


 classYourCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell { // collectionviewcell

  }
```

Comment: Thanks for ur contribution..@V_rohit